# Loop through multiple workbooks with different lengths?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have some code to loop through multiple workbooks:

```
wb = load_workbook(fileName)
for curTitle in wb.worksheets:
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = curTitle.title)
    for row in ws.range('A1:C100'):
        for cell in row:
             #Do Something
```

However the range is different in every worksheet. Is there a way to get the last row that has data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [documentation for openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/api.html#module-openpyxl-worksheet-worksheet).

If you look at the Worksheet module, you will see that your `ws` worksheet has functions like `calculate_dimension()`, `get_highest_row()`, and the like.

Comment: Thats great. I just needed to change: for row in ws.range(ws.calculate_dimension()): and it worked cheers

Answer (score 0):

Range("A1:C" & Range("A65536").End(xlup).Row)

assuming you have data up to the last row in col A

Comment: that would give you Range("A1:C100") if you have 100 rows of data, or Range("A1:C150") if you have 150 rows etc